# Android Studio, Gradle Update error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently updated Android Studio to version 0.2, and now when I build my code, I get this error, Please tell me how to overcome this.

> Gradle 'NewProject' project refresh failed:
>
> Project is using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in. The
>   minimum supported version is 0.5.0.    Please update the version of
>   the dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' in your build.gradle
>   files.    Search in build.gradle files (show balloon)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its a reported issue in Android Studio Build #AI-130.737825, built on July 11, 2013. Luckily, there is a workaround that you can do to fix this import issue.

Externally edit the project's build.gradle file, changing 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'

[Here is](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57533) the link to the issue

Comment: It should be changed to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+' instead of only 0.5.0

Comment: The project I am trying to import - https://code.google.com/p/iosched - already has classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'.  But I am still getting this error...  So I had to change it to 0.6.+.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your

> build.gradle

file and replace the string

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle: (what you have here)'

with

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5'

Comment: Got this Error:   Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
* What went wrong:
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'MyProject'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/home/vinuthan/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6'.

Comment: For this error try: "Download the full zip package from http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip manually and copy this zip package to C:\Documents and Settings\vinuthan\gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok\" for Windows, for Mac use ""~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/".

Comment: But i already have the file in the location you specified, Should i download it again ?

Comment: @g00dy I did what you suggested, but it didn't work! I am using ActionBarSherlock as a depended project, so I had to update it's build.gradle as well...